i stuck with reactotron and redux toolkit in my react-native project
i succeffully added redux-toolkit to my react-native project, work properly. But I can not add reactotron.
thats my ReactotronConfig.js
import Reactotron, {
  trackGlobalErrors,
  asyncStorage,
} from "reactotron-react-native";
import { reactotronRedux } from "reactotron-redux";

Reactotron.configure({
  name: "my-app",
})
  .use(asyncStorage())
  .use(trackGlobalErrors())
  .useReactNative({
    storybook: true,
  })
  .use(reactotronRedux())
  .connect();

export default Reactotron;

and store/index.tsx,
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";

import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

import Reactotron from "../../ReactotronConfig";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
  enhancers: __DEV__ ? [Reactotron.createEnhancer!()] : [], // GETS TYPE ERROR and Property 'createEnhancer' does not exist on type 'ReactotronReactNative'.ts(2339)
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

how can i add Reactotron to my store index file ? thanks for any help

https://blog.logrocket.com/exploring-redux-second-generation/
enhancers: getDefaultEnhancers =>
getDefaultEnhancers().concat(reactotron.createEnhancer!()),

Please provide more information with your answer.
